# How do I create a website menu bar like this?

Tags: jquery, web

[Apple iPhone 7 Page](http://www.apple.com/iphone-7/)
If you keep scrolling, you'll see that the menu bar sticks and the design is very nice (and it has a defined border).
How can I do something like this? I've tried lists with CSS, but they look horrible compared to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Bootstrap` check this one [Afix](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp)

Comment: THANKS! And say I have all these sections on one page, once I scroll down to that section, will the option on the menubar automatically be selected?

Comment: for that check http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: you are a beast!! Where do you find all these from?